# Template argument deduction failed, SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

When I compile this code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
void do_stuff(std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value, T> &t) {}

template <typename T>
void do_stuff(std::enable_if_t<std::is_class<T>::value, T> &t) {}

int main() {
    int i = 1;
    do_stuff(i);
    return 0;
}
```

GCC says:

```
37325975.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
37325975.cpp:11:15: error: no matching function for call to ‘do_stuff(int&)’
     do_stuff(i);
               ^
37325975.cpp:4:6: note: candidate: template<class T> void do_stuff(std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<_Tp>::value, T>&)
 void do_stuff(std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value, T> &t) {}
      ^
37325975.cpp:4:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
37325975.cpp:11:15: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T’
     do_stuff(i);
               ^
37325975.cpp:7:6: note: candidate: template<class T> void do_stuff(std::enable_if_t<std::is_class<T>::value, T>&)
 void do_stuff(std::enable_if_t<std::is_class<T>::value, T> &t) {}
      ^
37325975.cpp:7:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
37325975.cpp:11:15: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T’
     do_stuff(i);
           ^
```

I've also tried on msvc 2013.

Why do I get these errors?

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/D1c4b0)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the compiler says, that parameter type is non-deducible, so you would need to supply the template argument manually, like this:

```
do_stuff<int>(i);
```

A better option is to put the `std::enable_if` in the return type or template parameter list:

```
//Return type
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>
do_stuff(T &t) {}

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_class<T>::value> 
do_stuff(T &t) {}

//Parameter list
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>* = nullptr>
void do_stuff(T &t) {}

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_class<T>::value>* = nullptr > 
void do_stuff(T &t) {}
```

This way the template parameter can still be deduced:

```
do_stuff(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why do I get these errors?

Because template argument deduction fails for nested-name-specifier, which is [non-deduced contexts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts).

> The nested-name-specifier (everything to the left of the scope resolution operator ::) of a type that was specified using a qualified-id.
>
> ```
> // the identity template, often used to exclude specific arguments from deduction
> template<typename T> struct identity { typedef T type; };
> template<typename T> void bad(std::vector<T> x, T value = 1);
> template<typename T> void good(std::vector<T> x, typename identity<T>::type value = 1);
> std::vector<std::complex<double>> x;
> bad(x, 1.2);  // P1 = std::vector<T>, A1 = std::vector<std::complex<double>>
>               // P1/A1: deduced T = std::complex<double>
>               // P2 = T, A2 = double
>               // P2/A2: deduced T = double
>               // error: deduction fails, T is ambiguous
> good(x, 1.2); // P1 = std::vector<T>, A1 = std::vector<std::complex<double>>
>               // P1/A1: deduced T = std::complex<double>
>               // P2 = identity<T>::type, A2 = double
>               // P2/A2: uses T deduced by P1/A1 because T is to the left of :: in P2
>               // OK: T = std::complex<double>
> ```

Answer (score 2):

When the compiler tries to resolve `do_stuff(int&)`, it sees the two candidates that the compiler tells you about.  But it's not able to "work backwards" to find a `T` that satisfies `std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value, T> == int`, nor to find a `T` that satisfies `std::enable_if_t<std::is_class<T>::value, T> == int`.

As mentioned in [TartanLlama's answer](/a/37326048), the way to avoid this is to make the argument deducible (e.g. `do_stuff(T&)`) and make the *return type* or a *subsequent template argument* dependent on `T`.