# simple SFINAE example to overload function not compiling

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I am referring to this example [SFINAE example](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/sfinae-and-enable_if/#),

I have tried to run the sample,

```
//enable_if
template<bool, typename T = void>
struct enable_if {};
template <typename T>
struct enable_if<true, T> {
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
void do_stuff(typename enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type &t) {
    std::cout<< "Integral selected "<<std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void do_stuff(typename enable_if<std::is_class<T>::value, T>::type &t) {
    std::cout<<"Class selected " <<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int t =25;
    do_stuff(t);
    return 0;
}
```

But this wont compile, may I know why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Template argument deduction failed, SFINAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37325975/template-argument-deduction-failed-sfinae)

Comment: I believe they are related but different issues.

Comment: @NicolasTisserand Different issues how? They are identical issues.

Comment: OP asked about his own custom `enable_if` implementation. Other questions relates to the standard `enable_if_t` from `<type_traits>`. But the answer ends up being similar, in the end, indeed.

Comment: @NicolasTisserand This is exactly how one would implement `enable_if` - the fact the OP isn't using the `std` version has nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But this wont compile, may I know why?

Because, calling `do_stuff()` the type `T` can't be deduced through `enable_if`.

But works if you call `do_stuff()` explicating the type `T`

```
int t =25;
do_stuff<int>(t); // compile
```

To avoid this problem, I suggest you the solution proposed by Nicolas Tisserand (+1) (there is no need to explicate `void` as second parameter of `enable_if` because is the default)

```
template <typename T>
typename enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type
do_stuff(T& t) {
    std::cout<< "Integral selected "<<std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
typename enable_if<std::is_class<T>::value>::type
do_stuff(T& t) {
    std::cout<<"Class selected " <<std::endl;
}
```

with SFINAE enabled through return type.

This way the type `T` is deducible from the argument, so you doesn't need to explicate it.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other solutions, if you don't want the `enable_if` as a return value, you can pass it as a parameter type which is then part of the function signature:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

//enable_if
template<bool, typename T = void>
struct enable_if {};
template <typename T>
struct enable_if<true, T> {
    using type = int; // must be a non-type template parameter
};

template <typename T, typename enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type = 0>
void do_stuff(T &t) {
    std::cout<< "Integral selected "<<std::endl;
}

template <typename T, typename enable_if<std::is_class<T>::value, T>::type = 0>
void do_stuff(T &t) {
    std::cout<<"Class selected " <<std::endl;
}

class Foo
{
  public:
    Foo() = default;
};

int main()
{
    int t =25;
    Foo f;
    do_stuff(t);
    do_stuff(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
template <typename T>
typename enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, void>::type
do_stuff(T& t) {
    std::cout<< "Integral selected "<<std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
typename enable_if<std::is_class<T>::value, void>::type
do_stuff(T& t) {
    std::cout<<"Class selected " <<std::endl;
}
```

The problem was that the `enable_if` static calls were applied to the function parameters instead of the return types.